# Probability of walking into a pole

Tags: probability

I have a problem I am thinking about...someone posted on Facebook about randomly walking into a pole and it got me thinking.

Say there is a straight line of 100 metres, and in that straight line is one pole, of say, 0.2 metres wide. If the width of a person is 0.5 metres, and that person has to cross the line, what is the probability of him/her walking into the pole, assuming a uniform distribution?

So the person occupies 0.5% of the total area, but there are countably infinite areas that the person can occupy. The problem would become easy to solve if we broke the area up into intervals.

What is the most accurate way of solving a question similar to this? Are there any similar, well-known problems?

Comment: I think this is geometric probability, not sure though.

Comment: Probability depends on what country you are in.

Comment: Does the pole and person lie wholly in the line?

Comment: @copper.hat Wouldn't it depend on where the pole is? If the pole is at the endpoints of the line then it would have a different probability of occurring than if it was, say, in the middle of the line right?

Comment: @SherlockHolmes: That's why I am asking :-). I answered the simple version below.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks, I should learn to trust my intuition more haha :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the person and pole must lie entirely inside the line, then the person's position can be anywhere in $[0,100-0.5]$. The length of the interval of positions in which the person will bump into the pole is $0.5+0.2$ hence the probability is ${0.7 \over 99.5}$.

Comment: Nice and precise. +1.

Comment: You're a poet and you know it.

Comment: @copper.hat this is a much simpler way of approaching the problem...thank you!